# Convergence of sequence linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis

In $H_0^1\left( {0,1} \right)$, we define 
$${T_n}u = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {u\left( {\frac{i}{n}} \right)} ,Tu = \int_0^1 {u\left( x \right)dx} .$$
Easily to prove that ${T_n}u \to Tu$ for all $u \in H_0^1\left( {0,1} \right)$.
Can we prove ${T_n} \to T$ in $H^{-1}$ or subsequence of $T_n$ such that $T_n \to T$ in weak star topology?